# Spring security: user and admin login fails

Tags: java, mysql, spring-security

This should be a simple solution but I can't seem to figure it out.

Problem: Every time I try to login as either user or admin, the username and password always return "access denied for this user" (even though the usernames and the roles are indeed in the database).

Here are my files:

> **LoginController:**

```
@Controller
    public class LoginController {
        @RequestMapping("login")
         public ModelAndView getLoginForm(
           @RequestParam(required = false) String authfailed, String logout,
           String denied) {
          String message = "";
          if (authfailed != null) {
           message = "Invalid username of password, try again !";
          } else if (logout != null) {
           message = "Logged Out successfully, login again to continue !";
          } else if (denied != null) {
           message = "Access denied for this user !";
          }
          return new ModelAndView("login", "message", message);
         }

         @RequestMapping("user")
         public String geUserPage() {
          return "user";
         }

         @RequestMapping("admin")
         public String geAdminPage() {
          return "admin";
         }

         @RequestMapping("403page")
         public String ge403denied() {
          return "redirect:login?denied";
         }

    }
```

> security-servlet.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
  <access-denied-handler error-page="/403page" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/anonymous" access="isAnonymous"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
  <form-login login-page='/login' username-parameter="username"
   password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/user"
   authentication-failure-url="/login?authfailed" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
 </http>

 <authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
   <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
    authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I keep getting: access denied for this user

Comment: What is the value of "denied" that you are getting in controller?

Comment: It shows "login?denied"

Comment: I solved this just by simply using the right spring security version in pom.xml. Very stupid mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using the right security version in pom.xml